# Can't add viewContoller to Tab Bar programmatically in the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, downcast

I'm trying to add a viewController to the existing Tab Bar programmatically through `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`, but my code doesn't work, i can't downcast the rootViewController as UITabBarController.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            print("rootVC")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavController")
            vc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .topRated, tag: 1)
            tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(vc)
        }

        return true
    }
```

Here is my storyboard, i think here is all okay, Tab Bar Contoller is initial view Controller...

**Main.storyboard**
[image: Main.storyboard]

Comment: I was doing the same thing today with HWS, I'm pushing a PR for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 13+ the window will be nil from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate.  Instead move your code to `willConnectTo session` method in `SceneDelegate`:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        print("rootVC")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavController")
        vc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .topRated, tag: 1)
        tabBarController.viewControllers?.append(vc)
    }
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```